# Height of two tables rows same all the time

Tags: jquery, css

I have two tables, let's say table A and table B. They both will have always equal number of rows. Table A is frozen and table B is scrollable. Actually, frozen and scrollable aren't really relevant to my question but just throwing it out.

Now in order to make sure that the height of a row of table A is always equal to height of a row of table B with same index, I have used something like below:

```
    $(function() {
var numberOfRows = $("#Scroll table tbody tr").length;      
        for(i=1; i<numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            var currentHeight = $("#Scroll table tbody tr").eq(i).height();
            $("#Fixed table tbody tr").eq(i-1).css("height", currentHeight).css("vertical-align", "middle");
        }
});
```

First table is is included in div with id "Fixed" and other table is in div with id "Scroll"

I am not a jQuery expert so not sure if this is the most efficient, reliable way to do this. The issue I am having with this solution is, it renders fine but when I zoom the page to 125% or 150% the table alignment gets out of way.

Any suggestions, solutions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible problem is setting the height of the `tr`s. Don't think it's valid and probably it's not too browser agnostic.  Instead, change the height of the `td`s just to see if it works better.